# Get result set from stored procedure postgresql 11

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, ref-cursor

I want to get results set from a stored procedure (not a function) in PostgreSQL 11 version. I wrote below the stored procedure. But I couldn't get results set from that. Please help anyone!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_address (INOUT _result_one refcursor = 'rs_resultone') language 
plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
     OPEN _result_one FOR SELECT city, country FROM address;
END $$;
```

I executed the stored procedure as below.

```
BEGIN;
CALL sp_address('sss');
FETCH ALL FROM "rs_resultone";
END;
```

Then I got the below error.

ERROR:  cursor "rs_resultone" does not exist
SQL state: 34000

Comment: If you want to return a result, use a set-returning function. Procedures aren't meant for that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you! My requirement is to return a result set from the stored procedure. It possible to do in PostgreSQL. right? I saw some examples in google.

Comment: The way to "return a result" in Postgres is to use a function.